# Install packages on the fly

Tags: linux, archiving, yum, apt-get

Apt-get and other package managers download the necessary packages to disk, then install them and discard them.

I know it's possible to unpack archives like tar.gz or others directly as they are downloaded, instead of saving them to disk. Is there an option for apt-get (or an alternative) that does this?

It would be much faster especially for large packages.

Comment: What you're suggesting GZ does is probably it just saving it to a temporary spot on the disk and then opening it instead of asking you where you want to save it.

Comment: No, you can do e.g. "wget -O - URL | tar zxf -" and the tar.gz file is not saved anywhere

Comment: What you probably need is a bigger hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, apt-get can perform a download-only operation.

```
$ apt-get --help
[...]

Commands:
   [...]
   install - Install new packages (pkg is libc6 not libc6.deb)

Options:
  [...]
  -d  Download only - do NOT install or unpack archives
```

To only download packages (and their dependencies):

```
apt-get -d install [package_name ...]
```

Example:

```
$ sudo apt-get -d install openvpn
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  liblzo2-2 libpkcs11-helper1
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  liblzo2-2 libpkcs11-helper1 openvpn
0 upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
Need to get 563 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,444 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main liblzo2-2 i386 2.06-1ubuntu0.1 [60.8 kB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main libpkcs11-helper1 i386 1.09-1 [47.5 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main openvpn i386 2.2.1-8ubuntu1.4 [455 kB]
Fetched 563 kB in 0s (6,168 kB/s)
Download complete and in download only mode
```

The packages will be stored in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, not your current working directory.

Comment: Nevermind me. I misunderstood what you wanted to achieve here. I suppose you could use `dpkg-deb` to extract dpkg archives via a stdin stream, but it will not result in a valid installation, and the package's meta data will be lost, so what you want is probably not feasible.

Answer (score 1):

Debian and other distributions with strong dependency management probably wouldn't work well this way.  However, a distribution like Slackware which uses simple `.tgz` files extracted from the root `/` directory could be made to work like this.  I would be wary of trying to actually do it - what would happen if a download was corrupted, power loss in middle of process, etc?

Comment: I think Debian stores the metadata of installed packages in its internal database, regardless of the actual .deb files which would be deleted. Interrupted downloads would need to start over, so for slow or unstable connections it wouldn't be a good idea